# AWS DMS and Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-dms

I am using DMS to migrate data from MySQL to Redshift.
Inside DMS, I use the 'full-load-and-ongoing' option to load data to Redshift.
Assuming the full-load is complete and the on-going is in progress,I would like to know how I can resume the DMS task in case we restore Redshift using an old snapshot.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to

1. Stop the DMS task
2. Restore your target redshift
3. RESTART your DMS task. (This will do the initial copy again and then reinstate the continuous replication)

If you have made any modifications to the target tables then change your task to truncate rather than drop and create.

If you cannot have any downtime on your Redshift table then you could do the following.

1. Rename your existing Redshift table to be _inuse, e.g. if your table
   is called orders then call it orders_inuse
2. Create a new "late binding" view like this

   CREATE VIEW orders as
   SELECT * FROM orders_inuse
   WITH NO SCHEMA BINDING;
3. Set up DMS to replicate to orders_new table
4. Drop orders_inuse
5. recreate your view

   CREATE or replace VIEW orders as
   SELECT * FROM orders_new
   WITH NO SCHEMA BINDING;

Comment: Thanks Jon,
But this can either clear the data already present in Redshift or create duplicate entries in Redshift , both being a problem.
Need to avoid both of the mentioned scenarios .

Comment: Oh you want to do it WITHOUT clearing the data that is already in redshift? sorry i dont know how you can do that. why do you need to avoid that restart?

Comment: Yes Jon,
1. The data in Redshift is critical and is being used by 3rd party.
2.We cannot wait for the DMS to clear the data and load it from scratch.(that might take more than 1 2 hours depending on the amount of data)

Comment: can you use a different table / scema name and switch between old (existing) and new with a late binding view?

Comment: That is a good option Jon. Let me check it out and get back to you.
Appreciate your help.